# Using scryRenderedComponentsWithType or findRenderedComponentWithType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-testutils

I am trying to do some unit testing by using `findRenderedComponentWithType` and `findRenderedComponentWithType` to find components. However, I am having a bit of trouble.

I have a shallow rendered component `<Layout />` and within it, I want to find `<UserMenu />`.

```
var Layout = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div id="data-trader">
                <header className="header">
                    <UserMenu user={this.props.user} />
                </header>
                <SideMenu user={this.props.user}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Layout;
```

Within my test file, I tried this:

```
describe('Layout', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        fakeDOM = TestUtils.createRenderer();
        it('should exist as a component', function(done) {
            expect(<Layout/>).to.exist;
            done();
        });
        fakeDOM.render(<Layout />);
        renderedFakeDOMOutput = fakeDOM.getRenderOutput();
    });
    it('should have login button when props.user is undefined', function(done) {
        renderedFakeDOMOutput.props.user = undefined;
        let UserMenuComponent = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(renderedFakeDOMOutput, UserMenu);
        done();
    });
});
```

However, `scryRenderedComponentsWithType` and `findRenderedComponentWithType` cannot find anything of the components with the type `UserMenu`.

I also tried to create another file where it `exports` the `UserMenu` component but I get the same output or 0 found (Array length 0) or error when no components are found (`Error: Did not find exactly one match for componentType:function UserMenu()`).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a direct solution to the question you're asking, but when I tried shallow rendering, I struggled with it just as you are. React's own docs describe this feature as an early release with "some limitations".

> Shallow testing currently has some limitations, namely not supporting
>   refs. We're releasing this feature early and would appreciate the
>   React community's feedback on how it should evolve.

I got tired of banging my head against the wall and went with a more straight-forward solution that I found elsewhere.

http://substantial.com/blog/2014/11/11/test-driven-react-how-to-manually-mock-components/

In case that link ever goes bad: Basically, it says to use [Rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to swap out your sub-components with something you create inline in your test. Here is exactly what I do:

*rewire-module.js* (copied from the blog post)

```
module.exports = function rewireModule(rewiredModule, varValues) {
    var rewiredReverts = [];

    beforeEach(function () {
        var key, value, revert;
        for (key in varValues) {
            if (varValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                value = varValues[key];
                revert = rewiredModule.__set__(key, value);
                rewiredReverts.push(revert);
            }
        }
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        rewiredReverts.forEach(function (revert) {
            revert();
        });
    });

    return rewiredModule;
};
```

*MyList.jsx* (snippet)

```
<div>
    { items.map(item => <MyListItem key={item.id} item={item}/>) }
</div>
```

*MyList-test.jsx* (snippet)

```
let rewireModule = require('../utils/rewire-module');
let rewire = require('rewire');
let MyList = rewire('./MyList.jsx');

rewireModule(MyList, {
    MyListItem: React.createClass({
        propTypes: {
            item: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
        },
        render: function () {
            return <div className="MyListItem"/>;
        }
    })
});

it('should render data', function () {
    // init
    MyStore.onLoadCompleted([
        {id: 1, name: 'Test 1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Test 2'}
    ]);

    let listComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyList/>);
    let listItems = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(listComponent, 'MyListItem');
    expect(listItems.length).to.equal(2);

    // cleanup
    React.unmountComponentAtNode(listComponent.getDOMNode());
});
```

As you may have figured, I basically use "className" as my element identifiers to find them later.

Sometimes if I want to search for specific sub-components with specific data, I'll build something unique into the className.

```
rewireModule(MyList, {
    MyListItem: React.createClass({
        propTypes: {
            item: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
        },
        render: function () {
            return <div className={'MyListItem_' + item.id}/>;
        }
    })
});

it('should render data', function () {
    // init
    MyStore.onLoadCompleted([
        {id: 1, name: 'Test 1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Test 2'}
    ]);

    let listComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyList/>);
    TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(listComponent, 'MyListItem_1');
    TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(listComponent, 'MyListItem_2');

    // cleanup
    React.unmountComponentAtNode(listComponent.getDOMNode());
});
```